# Laravel 5.6 Access auth()->user() in controller constructor?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to access auth()->user() in controller constructor, but it always return `null`.

I have tried below, but no luck!

```
protected $user;

function __construct() {
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = auth()->user();

        return $next($request);
    }); 

}
```

Is there any way to do this?

--Thanks

Comment: Are you use auth middleware on this route?

Comment: yes, it's bind in routes

Comment: here it is `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'web']], function () {Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');});`

Comment: Did you have tried `\Auth::user()`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried all things, always get `null` value

Comment: where are you trying to use `$this->user` that you get `null`?

Comment: it seems controller middleware executed before route middleware, try adding `$this->middleware('auth');` before your middleware in __construct

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I have the exact same problem

Comment: Have you ever tried `$request->user()` and see if `user` exists instead of `auth()->user()` ?

Answer (score 4):

Controller Constructor is called before Middlewares. So you can not get User information inside Constructor().

My advice is create private function that sets User, and call this inside your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ts8060 i had the idea to create a singleton for doing that.

```
/** @var User */
private static $user;

/**
 * Singleton
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function getUser() {
    if(empty(static::$user)) {
        static::$user = Auth::user();
    }

    return static::$user;
}
```

Comment: why will this code work? where do I put this code? please elaborate

Answer (score -2):

I think that auth middleware run after create controller, you may do somethink like this in your controller

```
public function callAction($method, $parameters)
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
       $this->user = auth()->user();

       return $next($request);
    }); 

    return parent::callAction($method, $parameters);
}
```